# Sharepoint 2013 workflow: what to use to get the url of a secondary list and paste it into a field in first list

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a workflow on a simple list that creates a thread in a discussion board with the subject title that is the same title of the first list. I managed to do this part.

I need that the workflow takes the URL of the thread and pastes it in an empty hyperlink field. I struggle with this part, I have used Update Item, Set field in current item, no success with the copy-paste.

I remember doing it with the 2010 template and succeeding, now with the 2013, in addition I have the 'outcome' of the workflow saying 'stage 1'. At the end I did put go to end of workflow but apparently it stops before.

Comment: where's this field "empty hyperlink field" ?

Comment: It is the column Hyperlink or Picture. I have placed it in the original list (empty)

Comment: you need to get the URL of the new discussion that added via workflow and set this url to the current item hyperlink field  in the list , right ?

Comment: yes, and if it is correct that setting the Transition to stage = go to end of the wf, is the way to end it

Answer (score 0):

First Log the URL once it is formed and store it in a local workflow variable. Check it in Workflow History log if the correct URL is coming. Now use  the Action button **Set this field to the Current item** with the variable under which URL is stored. Once it is done, now Log the field value as well in Workflow history log and then end the workflow.

Note: The logging steps is just to debug the workflow if the correct hyperlink is formed and is getting stored in the field